# JavaFX: TableView message when empty

Tags: java, javafx, tableview, javafx-8

I'm working on a java project using Eclipse, javaFX, TableView.. My application is available in three languagues and user can change it from the Setting corner in the app and everything goes right, but i noteced that when a table is empty it show this message or hint line:

[image]

As you can see even if user change language this line still in french(My system language) and i don't find any way to change it, change its content or hide it..
Please if anyone can help me in this just post an idea or comment.

Thanks..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this to set the empty tableview message accordingly each time when language is changed: `tableview.setPlaceholder(new Label("Empty tableview!"));`